# Java regex to match for variable value

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to extract the value of a particular variable in a text file that I'm parsing containing code. The variable name changes, as does its position in the code, but I know the pattern therefore I successfully obtain its value and store it in a variable, called myVar.

To get the value, i.e. the string between quotes after the myVar and equals sign, i.e. `myVar = "value i want is here"` I thought about using regex as follows:

```
Pattern q = Pattern.compile(myVar + "\= \"(.*)\"" );
```

But I get an error when compiling:

> error: illegal escape character
>   Pattern q = Pattern.compile(myVar + "\= \"(.*)\"" );

Is this something to do with concatenating the myVar string with the regular expression?

Comment: What's in the variable `myVar` at runtime?

Comment: @Asaph a string of the form `variable_name[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\=` is not an escape sequence.
You probably need to escape the Regex string for java. Here is a link for doing that:
http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

```
Escape Sequences
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: @Xlsx is right. Change `\=` to either `=` or `\\=` (if you *really* want the leading backslash in there, although there isn't any point to having it).

Comment: The problem with `\=` is not a regex issue at all. `\=` isn't valid in a java String. It's not even getting as far as compiling the regex because the java code doesn't even compile.

Comment: ok, removed the backslash and it compiles, but doesnt return any value in the group, so must have another issue somewhere. thanks. i'll keep checking.

Comment: You probably also have to add another backslash to the ones before the quotes, because java recognizes \" as only ", you should write \\"